# Rotary switch for bench supply ammeter

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, switches

I plan to build a bench supply using a used ATX desktop computer PSU, with 3.3v, 5v and 12v binding posts as well as a cheap voltmeter-ammeter combo module (DSN-VC288). I know it's going to be inaccurate and have terrible ripple, but it would still be a nice addition to the variable bench supply I already have.

Now, I would like to add a rotary band switch to toggle the voltmeter-ammeter module between the three outputs. However, passing the output current through the band switch is not an option, as the switch is only rated for 300 mA, and the supply should go up to at least 5A (will be adding fuses on each of the outputs).

I have a bunch of IRFZ44N MOSFETs lying around which can handle 35A continuous DC, so my first instinct is to use those to switch the currents when the rotary switch is turned. However, I wonder if I am overcomplicating it - or using the wrong tool for the job?

I am fairly new to electronics so it's very possible that there is a standard way to do this that I'm just not familiar with. Or is the MOSFET route a viable solution?

Comment: I'm guessing you want something robust for this application--perhaps go with a relay-based solution. Either way though, some ATX power supplies will refuse to turn on if there's no load on some of their outputs, (my understanding is that this is because they're designed to be used in a very specific situation and not powering up when only some outputs are plugged in protects things from damage)

Comment: @Hearth thanks, yes I plan to use a power resistor as a load on the 5V rail to keep the PSU on. As for relays, makes sense but could the slower switching be a problem?

Comment: do you need a common ground between all 3 when not being metered? If so, that seems to contra-indicate the NCHAN fet idea, unless you get a higher voltage mosfet driver, but then you're really getting complex for a switch replacement. I would consider stand-alone SPST switches that can "mux" the lines, even if you only use 1 at a time...

Comment: @dandavis I don't exactly work with them on a regular basis, I'm just relaying advice I've seen given to others on here.

Comment: @Hearth: fair enough, I'm just saying a LOT of people waste power+heat on these types of home-brews. If there's a 3.3v sense line (brown), it shouldn't be superstitious about minimum load. 100% correlation in the couple dozen i've seen...

Comment: @JensRoland In light of what dandavis said, perhaps skip the resistor load if it works without it. I doubt the slower switching would be a problem.

Comment: @dandavis good point, I don't think I need a common ground for the outputs. The muxing with SPST switches actually crossed my mind as a low-complexity solution, I just thought a rotary dial would be neater.

Comment: @Hearth will definitely check the PSU to see if it requires the internal space heater / current waster to run. Hopefully as dandavis mentions it might not need it at all.

Comment: I would guess that module requires an external current shunt. In which case you can dedicate one to each of the three outputs and switch the sense lines.

Comment: @sstobbe that sounds very interesting - could you elaborate a little on how that might be wired up? (in a regular answer maybe?) It sounds like exactly the right way to do what I need.

Comment: @sstobbe now I’ve read up on shunting a bit— and just to clarify: I would place a shunt between the common ground and each of the negative binding posts, so I can connect up the negative side sense wire to all three shunts and just switch the positive side sense wire between the shunts? Or should I switch both sense wires for accuracy? My band switch is 4P3T so I can do either.

Comment: You don't need to pass any output at all through the switch.  Just run sense leads from the actual outputs to the switch for voltage, and a single common-side shunt sense lead for current.

Comment: @JensRoland Hello, I am not familiar with that panel meter, I don't know if the current shunt can float or must be referenced to the negative supply of the meter. There is a downside with low side sensing, if your circuit uses multiple supply rails the return current can run through any of binding posts, yielding inaccurate readings (some high, some low).

Comment: @sstobbe Hmm.. but with high side sensing I would have to switch both sense leads, right? Since the three shunts are on completely different potentials they can’t have a common side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to get a current meter that can use an external shunt, then place one shunt on each output and route the shunt connections through the rotary switch. This way, you are not going to be switching the current path at all, which not only simplifies the design, it also ensures that the supply to the load is not interrupted when switching the meter to a different output.

Comment: Thanks - this seems to be the right solution; I just need to determine if I should do the sensing on the high or on the low side, and whether on the low side I would have to switch both sense leads or if one would be enough (with common ground)

Comment: I think you're going to want to do the sensing on the high side.  The power supply you're using probably has a common ground across all of the outputs, so measuring the current on the low side of your output terminals won't tell you much of anything useful if you have two outputs connected to the same circuit.  Measuring on the high side will actually give you the correct current for each output.  If the power supply channels were totally isolated from each other, then this would not be a problem and low side current sense would work fine.

Comment: @alex.forencich Could you provide a simple schematic of how this might work?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would probably be to use relays. If you're concerned about the switching delays or even the sound produced during switching, use solid state relays. They are quite fast, and essentially employ FETs for switching purposes. So you're just replacing your MOSFETs for better packed versions of the same.

However, in my experience, I've found that both of them heat up quite often. This might provide a more detailed view-https://www.ia.omron.com/support/guide/18/overview.html